# Dynamic memory allocation for 2D arrays (C)

Tags: c, arrays, memory-management, multidimensional-array

I've noticed that I lack of knowledge of dynamic 2D arrays, after reading some topics here and around the web I've tried something but it seem not to behave correctly: 
I want to allocate a 3X3 array of integers, input values in to it and display them, the problem is that always after I enter a value at the index of `[3][1]` the program crashes... it is weird because I think that I've done everything correctly.
I would also like to hear your thoughts about checking for memory allocation failure,`(!(array))` good enough method? I've also seen some examples of deallocating memory up to the failure point, if one occurred.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
int i, j, //loop control
    **array, //pointer to hold the 2D array
    N = 3; //rows and columns quantity
array = malloc (N * sizeof (int*)); //allocating rows
if (!(array)) //checking for allocation failure
{
    printf("memory allocation failed!\n");
    goto exit;
}
else
{
    array [i] = calloc (N, sizeof (int)); //allocating columns
    if (!(array[i])) //checking for allocation failure
    {
        printf("memory allocation failed!\n");
        goto exit;
    }
}

for (i = 0; i < N; i++) //getting user input
{
    for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
    {
        printf("Enter value [%d][%d]:", i+1, j+1);
        scanf ("%d", &array [i][j]);
    }
}
for (i = 0; i < N; i++) //displaying the matrix
{
    printf("\n");
    for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
    {
        printf (" %d", array [i][j]);
    }
}
exit:
return 0;
```

}

Comment: If `N` is `3` then the valid indices are `0`, `1`, `2`. Accssing `[3][1]` is out of bounds.  Your `calloc` statements are correct but you forgot to add a loop for `i` - you need to allocate each row when using this method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have couple of problems.

1. You are using uninitialized `i`.
2. You haven't allocated memory for all the rows. The following line can allocate memory for only one row.

   ```
   array [i] = calloc (N, sizeof (int)); //allocating columns
   ```

What you need:

Instead of

```
array [i] = calloc (N, sizeof (int)); //allocating columns
if (!(array[i])) //checking for allocation failure
{
    printf("memory allocation failed!\n");
    goto exit;
}
```

Use

```
for ( i = 0; i < N; ++i )
{
  array [i] = calloc (N, sizeof (int)); //allocating columns
  if (!(array[i])) //checking for allocation failure
  {
      printf("memory allocation failed!\n");
      goto exit;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I just noticed it myself... that means that it's time to go to sleep if I made a mistake of this sort, thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

You got lucky it didn't crash earlier.  You only allocated one row of the 3x3 matrix:

```
array [i] = calloc (N, sizeof (int)); //allocating columns
if (!(array[i])) //checking for allocation failure
{
    printf("memory allocation failed!\n");
    goto exit;
}
```

You need to do this for *each* row of the matrix, not just once.
Furthermore, when you call `calloc`, the value of `i` is undefined.  Wrapping the above block in a foor loop should fix your issue:

```
else
{
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        array [i] = calloc (N, sizeof (int)); //allocating columns

        if (!(array[i])) //checking for allocation failure
        {
            printf("memory allocation failed!\n");
            goto exit;
        }
    }
}
```